# Why RecyclerView Adapter updating the instance of list of object that was passed to it

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, android-recyclerview

I am having an issue with `recyclerview.adapter` what i am doing is 
Passing a list of objects to a dialog where dialog have a recyclerview and two buttons.
1. Cancel and 2. Done
If user selects items from recyclerview that will be passed to fragment. 
Now assume if user have 2 items already selected, and opens dialog for more and selected some items but now user wants to cancel the selection and go back(without unselecting the ites) to fragment with old data but currently it is updating the list of object of fragment.

Here is the code of dialog.

```
fun showChooserDialog(
    baseActivity: AppCompatActivity,
    typeCode: Int,
    dataList: ArrayList<PrefsStateModel>
) {
    var alertDialog: AlertDialog? = null
    val dialogBuilder =
        AlertDialog.Builder(baseActivity, R.style.CustomDialog)
    dialogBuilder.setCancelable(true)
    val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(baseActivity)
    val dialogView: View = inflater.inflate(R.layout.view_select_prefs, null)
    dialogBuilder.setView(dialogView)
    val btnCancel = dialogView.findViewById<MaterialButton>(R.id.btnCancel)
    val btnDone = dialogView.findViewById<MaterialButton>(R.id.btnDone)
    val recyclerView = dialogView.findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.listViewPrefs)
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true)
    val layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(baseActivity)
    recyclerView.layoutManager = layoutManager
    val adapter =
        SelectPrefAdapter(
            baseActivity,
            dataList
        )
    recyclerView.adapter = adapter
    btnCancel.setOnClickListener {
        preferenceView.onUserNotSelected()
        alertDialog?.dismiss()
    }
    btnDone.setOnClickListener {
        val data = adapter.getList()
        preferenceView.onUserSelectedPrefDone(data, typeCode)
        alertDialog?.dismiss()
    }

    alertDialog = dialogBuilder.create()
    alertDialog.window?.setLayout(600, 400)
    alertDialog.show()
}
```

What i wants to do when user clicks on cancel button even he selected the more items from recyclerview, then the fragment's recyclerview should not update the items. it must be showing the old items. but currently it is updating the items even i am not passing when clicking on cancel button.

Here is adapter's code.

```
class SelectPrefAdapter(var context: Context, var dataList: ArrayList<PrefsStateModel>) :
RecyclerView.Adapter<SelectPrefAdapter.UserViewHolder>() {

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, p1: Int) =
    UserViewHolder(
        LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.view_pref_adapter, parent, false)
    )

override fun getItemCount() = dataList.size

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: UserViewHolder, position: Int) {
    var prefsState = dataList[position]
    holder.lable.text = prefsState.name

    if (prefsState.isSelected) {
        holder.lable.setTextColor(context.resources.getColor(R.color.colorPrimary))
        holder.icon.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    } else {
        holder.lable.setTextColor(context.resources.getColor(R.color.colorGreyShade2))
        holder.icon.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
    }

    holder.lable.setOnClickListener {
        if (prefsState.isSelected) {
            prefsState.isSelected = false
            holder.lable.setTextColor(context.resources.getColor(R.color.colorPrimary))
            holder.icon.visibility = View.VISIBLE

        } else {
            prefsState.isSelected = true
            holder.lable.setTextColor(context.resources.getColor(R.color.colorGreyShade2))
            holder.icon.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
        }
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }
}

class UserViewHolder(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
    val icon = view.imageViewIcon
    val lable = view.textviewPrefName
}


fun getList(): ArrayList<PrefsStateModel> {
    return dataList
}
}
```

This is main adapter code from where i pass the data to dialog's recyclerview adapter.

```
class ProfilePrefAdapter(
var context: Context,
var dataListPref: ArrayList<PrefsStateModel>,
var onPrefSelection: OnPrefSelection
) :
RecyclerView.Adapter<ProfilePrefAdapter.PrefViewHolder>() {

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, p1: Int) = PrefViewHolder(
    LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.view_pref, parent, false)
)

override fun getItemCount() = dataListPref.size

override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int {
    return super.getItemViewType(position)
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: PrefViewHolder, position: Int) {
    val prefs = dataListPref[position]
    holder.chipView.text = prefs.name
    if (prefs.isSelected) {
        holder.chipView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.rounded_border_selected)
        holder.chipView.setTextColor(context.resources.getColor(R.color.colorWhite))
    } else {
        holder.chipView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.rounded_border_unselected)
        holder.chipView.setTextColor(context.resources.getColor(R.color.colorGreyShade1))
    }
    if (position == dataListPref.size - 1) {
        onPrefSelection.onPrefSelection(getSelected())
    }

    holder.chipView.setOnClickListener {
        if (prefs.isSelected) {
            prefs.isSelected = false
            holder.chipView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.rounded_border_unselected)
            holder.chipView.setTextColor(context.resources.getColor(R.color.colorGreyShade1))
        } else {
            prefs.isSelected = true
            holder.chipView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.rounded_border_selected)
            holder.chipView.setTextColor(context.resources.getColor(R.color.colorWhite))
        }
        notifyDataSetChanged()
        onPrefSelection.onPrefSelection(getSelected())
    }
}

class PrefViewHolder(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
    val chipView = view.textViewPref
}

fun setList(data: ArrayList<PrefsStateModel>) {
    clearData()
    dataListPref.addAll(data)
    notifyDataSetChanged()
}

private fun clearData() {
    dataListPref.clear()
}

fun getData(): List<PrefsStateModel> {
    return dataListPref.toMutableList()
}

private fun getSelected(): Int {
    var count = 0
    for (data in dataListPref) {
        if (data.isSelected) {
            count++
        }
    }
    return count
}

}
```

This is where i am getting data and passing to dialog.

```
private fun showDialog(type: Int) {
    var dataToPasses: ArrayList<PrefsStateModel>? = ArrayList()
    when (type) {
        1 -> {
            dataToPasses?.clear()
            dataToPasses?.addAll(adapterGener!!.getData())
        }
        2 -> {
            dataToPasses?.clear()
            dataToPasses?.addAll(adapterContent!!.getData())
        }
        3 -> {
            dataToPasses?.clear()
            dataToPasses?.addAll(adapterLanuage!!.getData())
        }

    }
    utils.showLog(TAG, "data to be sent to dialog $dataToPasses and $generPrefList")
    preferencePresenter.showChooserDialog(baseActivity, type, dataToPasses!!)

}
```

Comment: When you pass list from current adapter to dialog, it will be the reference to the current list, it means everything update affect current list too. I recommend you method getList return dataList.toMutableList()

Comment: I assume you will be call getList from adapter to pass to method showChooserDialog

Comment: I added fragment's adapter code.

Comment: First i set data to `ProfilePrefAdapter` using `getData()` then creates recyclerview in dialog, now if i selects any item and click to cancel button that will do dismiss the dialog but the fragment's recyclerview will update the selected item. these items are not supposed to updated because i clicked cancel and only dismiss the dialog.

Answer (score 0):

It's happing because your `fragment` and `recyclreview` are working on the same object list its called `shallow copy`. time both has the latest copies of data. to solve this problem you need to create deep copy and pass that to the adapter.

Example

```
ArrayList<PrefsStateModel> newList = new ArrayList<PrefsStateModel>();

    for(PrefsStateModel p : oldList) {
        newList.add(p.clone());
    }


public class PrefsStateModel{

    String s;
    Date d;
    ...

    public PrefsStateModel clone(){
        PrefsStateModel p = new PrefsStateModel();
        p.s = this.s.clone();
        p.d = this.d.clone();
        ...
        return p;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please explain some more.

Comment: You can read more about deep copy https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-clone-a-list-in-java/

Comment: I done that way like adding all but still its updating the original data of fragment.